# How to set transparent to see through surface underneath in Microsoft.DirectX at top view?

Tags: c#, directx, transparent, direct3d, directx-9

I render a 3D data by setting `device.RenderState.AlphaBlendEnable = true`

it gives a side view like below:
[image: Pic1 shows side view @ solid filled mode]

[image: Pic2 shows side view @ wired frame mode]

Now my top view looks like this, the outer surface layer covered the underneath layers and resulting only outer layer is displayed at top view.

[image: Pic3 shows top view @ solid filled mode]

I would like to view the underneath layer from top view. How do I do this? Is there any setting can be done in `Microsoft.DirectX` ?

**Update: Question is solved by myself**

```
device.RenderState.ZBufferWriteEnable = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
device.RenderState.ZBufferWriteEnable = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting that allows this.  You need to, ideally, sort all the layers so they are drawn back-to-front.

Failing that you could use something like an "additive" blend that is not order dependent.

Finally there is a method called [depth peeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_peeling) that allows you to do order-independent transparency.